# Jquery - clicar em botão para fazer o show de listagem e hide de botão?

Tags: jquery

Boas, eu implementei uma listagem e tenho um botão em que se clicar aparecem mais elementos. No entanto eu quero que esse botão depois desapareça. Eu implementei este código, mas o botão não desaparece:

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#fotos").fadeIn();
       $("#button").hide();
    });
</script>
```

A única coisa que acontece é o fadein da listagem das fotos com id=fotos. 
Obrigada.

Comment: Claudia, no começo você usou `$("button")` como um elemento, e no hide  `$("#button")` como um id. Acho que está ai o seu erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o @Pedro disse defina um id para o seu botão:

```
<button id="button" ...>
```

ou no lugar do `id` pode utilizar o `this` para esconder o elemento que ativou o evento `click`:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
   $("#fotos").fadeIn();
   $(this).hide();
 });
```